# drawing from viewcontroller class swift

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect, setneedsdisplay

I made a class that inherits from UIView. In that class I want to draw a png image. However, when I run it in my viewcontroller, it doesn't seem to do anything. I read that we had to use setNeedsDisplay to be able to get the drawRect to be called in the viewcontroller. It doesn't seem to update.

```
class MyView: UIViewController{
    let tile = DrawTile()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
         tile.setNeedsDisplay()

    }
}

class Draw: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let image = UIImage(named: "test.png")
        let location = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        image?.drawAtPoint(location)

    }
}
```

Comment: tile is a Draw or a DrawTile?

Comment: can you see the image when you start the application?

Comment: I don't see the image when I start the application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing your view somewhere? drawRect() will only get called when you initialize your custom view and add it to your ViewController view. So it should look something like this:

```
    func createCustomView(){

    customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    customView.something = something

    self.view.addSubview(customView)

}
```

do it in viewDidLoad() and everything should be ok

Comment: I tried

    let tile = DrawTile(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))

    view.addSubview(tile)

and it showed the image. Is there a way where i can initialize the frame to the whole size of the phone instead of just 0,0,50,50? I then want to just grab the dimensions and print only a portion of the png.

Comment: to get a whole screen frame use:`let tile = DrawTile(frame:self.view.frame)` where self.view is a UIViewController's view.